# Make recursive function stack - safe with Free Monads Trampoline in Scala?

Tags: scala, recursion, scalaz, scala-cats

I've specified trait for my model:

```
sealed trait TreeStructureModel{
  val parentId: Option[Long]
  val title: String
  val id: Long
}
```

Then I'm building a tree from the records from the DB:

```
trait SimpleTree[+TreeStructureModel]{
  val title: String
  val id: Long
}
trait Node[+TreeStructureModel] extends SimpleTree[TreeStructureModel]{
  val inner: List[SimpleTree[TreeStructureModel]]
}
trait Leaf[+TreeStructureModel] extends SimpleTree[TreeStructureModel]

case class NodeImp[T <: TreeStructureModel](title: String, inner: List[SimpleTree[T]], id: Long) extends Node[T]
case class LeafImp[T <: TreeStructureModel](title: String, id: Long) extends Leaf[T]

object SimpleTree{
  def apply[T <: TreeStructureModel](ls: List[T]): List[SimpleTree[T]] = {
    def build(ls: List[T], current: T): SimpleTree[T] = {
      val children = ls.filter{ v => v.parentId.isDefined && v.parentId.get == current.id}
      if(children.isEmpty){
        LeafImp(title = current.title, id = current.id)
      } else {
        val newLs = ls.filterNot{ v => v.parentId.isDefined && v.parentId.get == current.id}
        NodeImp(title = current.title, id = current.id, inner = children.map{ch => build(newLs, ch)})
    }
  }
    val roots = ls.filter{ v => v.parentId.isEmpty}
    val others = ls.filterNot{ v => v.parentId.isEmpty}
    roots.map(build(others, _))
  }
}
```

This code works fine but uses non-tail recursive calls. So, my concern is that it will fail on big list of records. I've found a great [article](https://espinhogr.github.io/scala/2015/07/12/trampolines-in-scala.html) on using Free monads Trampoline over a non-tail recursion. 
This looks like a way to go but I can't rewrite my code to make it stack safe. In the example in the article there is only one recursive call in the function but in my function there can be a lot, to build a tree. Can somebody more experienced with Free monads help me with this? Is this even possible?

Comment: The length of the list is not a concern, but the depth of the tree is. You could change the `build` method to return `Trampoline[SimpleTree]` and instead of `children.map{ch => build(newLs, ch)}` use `children.traverse{ch => build(newLs, ch)}`, but also you could just implement it tail-recursively directly, by building the trees bottom-up (from leaves).

Comment: Can you show more details? When change result of the build method to Trampoline[SimpleTree] then children.traverse{ ch => build(newLs, ch)} got type mismatch error on build(newLs, ch)

Comment: See in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment, making the `build` method return a `Trampoline` and using `traverse` in place of `map`:

```
import scalaz.Free.Trampoline
import scalaz.Trampoline
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
import scalaz.std.list._

sealed trait TreeStructureModel{
  val parentId: Option[Long]
  val title: String
  val id: Long
}

trait SimpleTree[+TreeStructureModel]{
  val title: String
  val id: Long
}
trait Node[+TreeStructureModel] extends SimpleTree[TreeStructureModel]{
  val inner: List[SimpleTree[TreeStructureModel]]
}
trait Leaf[+TreeStructureModel] extends SimpleTree[TreeStructureModel]

case class NodeImp[T <: TreeStructureModel](title: String, inner: List[SimpleTree[T]], id: Long) extends Node[T]
case class LeafImp[T <: TreeStructureModel](title: String, id: Long) extends Leaf[T]

object SimpleTree{
  def apply[T <: TreeStructureModel](ls: List[T]): List[SimpleTree[T]] = {
    def build(ls: List[T], current: T): Trampoline[SimpleTree[T]] = {
      val children = ls.filter{ v => v.parentId.isDefined && v.parentId.get == current.id}
      if(children.isEmpty){
        Trampoline.done(LeafImp(title = current.title, id = current.id))
      } else {
        val newLs = ls.filterNot{ v => v.parentId.isDefined && v.parentId.get == current.id}
        children.traverse(build(newLs, _)).map(trees => NodeImp(title = current.title, id = current.id, inner = trees))
      }
    }
    val roots = ls.filter{ v => v.parentId.isEmpty}
    val others = ls.filterNot{ v => v.parentId.isEmpty}
    roots.map(build(others, _).run)
  }
}
```

Note that I did minimal necessary changes to your code to use `Trampoline`. I would further suggest to use a single call to [`partition`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partition(p:A=>Boolean):(Repr,Repr)) instead of a pair of `filter` and `filterNot`.

It would still be a good exercise to make the method tail-recursive directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer and great advice to use partition

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your function as tail-recursive, without scalaz. Occam's razor, you know ...

```
 def build(
   ls: List[T], 
   kids: Map[Long, List[T]],
   result: Map[Long, SimpleTree[T]]
 ) = ls match {
   case Nil => result
   case head :: tail if result.contains(head.id) => build(tail, kids, result)
   case head :: tail =>          
     kids(head.id).partition(result.contains(_.id)) match {
       case (Nil, Nil) => 
         build(tail, kids, result + (head.id->LeafImp(head.title, head.id)))
       case (done, Nil) => 
         build(
           tail,
           kids, 
           result + 
           (head.id->NodeImp(head.title, head.id, done.map(_.id).map(result)))
         )
       case (_, missing) =>
         build(missing ++ tail, kids, result)
     }
  }

  def apply(ls: List[T]) = {
    val (roots, others) = list.partition(_.parentId.isEmpty)
    val nodes = build(ls, others.groupBy(_.parentId.get), Map.empty)
    roots.map(_.id).map(nodes)
  }
```

Comment: There is something wrong in your code. This doesn't return a tree but Map of Leafs

Comment: `build` returns a Map of all nodes (not just leaves), `apply` returns a list of roots.

Comment: For me build always returns Map of LeafImps and apply just returns roots from them

Comment: Yes, thank you anyway. I got the idea and will play with your version to find out what is wrong

Comment: Oh, I got it. The condition in `tail.partition` was wrong ... I fixed it. Should be all better now.

Comment: This didn't help. I find out that there is some incorrect logic. When all kids are already in result and we are processing their parent tail.partition gives us no kids and we are going to case (Nil, Nil) producing LeafImp for their parent

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a bummer ... Gotta keep the list of kids around. 
Updated it again - pre-compute the children for all nodes, and pass them around as a separate param rather than filtering the list every time (this is also more efficient).